# Whatever happened to the spring parent bean?

Tags: spring, annotations, parent-child

I'm new to Spring 3, and its fancy additional annotations in particular

I have no idea how to have a controller class `B`, that extends controller class `A`, where `A` is defined via the xml files to have something useful - say, a db connection or whatever.

If I have an (abstract) parent bean `A`, and a concrete bean `B`, and `B` is a controller, AND i'm using the annotations-auto-wiring (you know, 
    `<context:component-scan base-package="package"/>`
), can I somehow tie `B` to `A`? Do i use annotations? Where do i define `A`, given that `A` needs to have some random spring bean put into it?

Comment: If you want answers, ask clear, concise questions--doesn't seem that overbearing.

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. Don't put that db connection in a controller class, put it in a db connection class. Your class `B` can then depend on a db connection, and when a `B` is needed it will be created and injected with the db connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a database connection in your controller, as @Shakedown mentions, is a bad practice. I know it's just an example, but I wanted to make sure that was pointed out.

With Spring annotations, you can get away from XML almost completely, for most projects.

It is common to have an `AbstractController` class, from which other concrete classes are derived.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/action")
public class AController extends AbstractController
{
    @Autowired
    private AService aService;
    ...
}
```

Dependencies can be injected into Spring classes using the `@Autowired` annotation. If you want to inject dependencies into your AbstractController, which is not technically a Spring managed class - you can make it one simply by adding the `@Component` annotation.

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractController
{
    @Autowired
    protected CommonService commonService;

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMyException(MyException e)
    {  
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.addObject("errorMessage", e.getMessage());

        model.setViewName("error");

        return model;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then use the dependency in your subclasses.

Comment: Thanks that was what i wanted! But question, why would I try and override the AbstractController, instead of just defining my own AbstractController-derived abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer - but it is the solution for i took in the end! It pretty much just expands on the answer given by Beau and skaffman, I'm just putting it here to be complete.

Given:

```
@Controller
class B extends A {

... B things done here! They use something!

}
```

and

```
abstact class A {

 private Object something;

 public void setSomething(Object something);
 public Object getSomething();
}
```

and where I used to have:

```
<bean id="A" abstract="true"
    class="package.to.A">
    <property name="something">
        <bean ref to something here>
    </property>        
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="B" parent="A"
    class="package.to.B">
</bean>
```

I know have (dun dun DUUUN):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.to.A"/>

<bean ref to something here with an id - it was an inner bean before>

<!-- no A or B beans defined -->
```

and

```
abstact class A {

 @Autowired
 private Object something;

 public void setSomething(Object something);
 public Object getSomething();
}
```

I didn't need the @Component on my AbstractController-derived abstract class, but I take it you mean i need the @Component if I want to do something with abstractController?